# Flutter Get setting variables properly

Tags: flutter, permissions, future, flutter-getx

So I'm slowly getting the hang of the GetX package usage after just finally learning  about flutter and stateless and stateful widgets.In this example i'm trying to understand how to properly create and set variables in GetX. So I'm trying to check for permissions and when I do this inside a method it works...

```
var cameraStatus = await Permission.camera.status;
```

but I want this variable in the class level not in the method so I try to create it like this above the method...

```
var cameraStatus = Permission.camera.status.obs;
```

but when I use this in the method...

```
cameraStatus.value = await Permission.camera.status;
```

I get the error "A value of type 'PermissionStatus' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Future'. Try changing the type of the variable, or cast the right-hand type to 'Future'."

Can someone enlighten me on how I'm supposed to create variables with Getx properly please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that just because you're using Getx, not everything needs to be made into observable streams with `.obs`.

While you can make custom objects observable, ask yourself why you feel the need to. Usually there's gonna be an easier way that accomplish what you need.

For example what you have here:

```
var cameraStatus = Permission.camera.status.obs;
```

Personally I don't see any value into changing a custom `PermissionStatus` type from an external package into an observable stream. Just use it as they show in the docs.

If you need to rebuild something based on the result of the permission request, you can use `GetBuilder` from Getx or `FutureBuilder` from the Flutter SDK.

Or if you want to use `Obx` widget then update the value of an `RxBool` based on permissions and rebuild your UI off of that. Personally if I have a project with GetX, I'm using `GetBuilder` for the vast majority of any UI updates I need. It will rebuild based on the change of any type once you call update.

All the app needs to know is a simple true or false of whether it has permission or not. So my suggestion is to just keep it simple.

```
class PermissionController extends GetxController {
  bool hasCameraPermission = false;

  Future<void> checkCameraPermission() async {
    final status = await Permission.camera.status;

    if (status == Permission.camera.isGranted) {
      hasCameraPermission = true;
      update(); // only needed if you're using GetBuilder widget
      return; // ending the function here because that's all you need.
    }

    if (status.isDenied) {
      await Permission.camera.request();
    }
    // ...continue to handle all the possible outcomes
    update();
  }
}
```

This also saves you from errors that you're getting from comparing unequal data types like you're doing here.

```
cameraStatus.value = await Permission.camera.status;
```

Then whatever part of your UI that depends on permissions could look like this

```
GetBuilder<PermissionController>(
            builder: (controller) {
              return controller.hasCameraPermission ? SomeWidget() : SomeOtherWidget();
            },
          )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, after reading about GetX and it potentially removing the need to use stateful widgets, guess I have it in my head that GetX will lower the overhead of resources and boost overall performance. I had a separate issue that was in the same widget creation here... [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70932062/flutter-futurebool-rxbool-and-regular-bool-confusion-and-how-to-get-the-va?noredirect=1#comment125396816_70932062) which after your example I def went overboard and made it complicated. Being new I'm still in the 1/4 knowledge in writing flutter and 3/4 script kitty

Comment: I needed to keep track of the status cause I was trying to create a reusable widget to have a separate button for each permission I was checking. So I have a permission controller that has all the methods for each permission check then I made a widget of a button setup thats dynamically changed depending on which permission and what status it was. I have been preferring the Obx approach so far and not needing to do the GetBuilder function. Is there a performance difference between the 2 that you prefer the getBuilder?

Comment: `Obx` is fine I still use it when I actually can actually benefit from a stream. My only point was I wouldn't try and turn custom objects into streams unless there's a real need for it. Primitive types `bool` `string` etc... are easy to add `.obs` and use `Obx` with. Overall streams by their nature are a bit more expensive than primitive types so in theory `GetBuilder` would be a bit more performant than `Obx`. But that's unlikely to be a noticeable difference as far as the user is concerned. I like `GetBuilder` because it doesn't care about the type, you call `update()` and it will rebuild.

Comment: Thanks for the advice I will keep that in mind. I only make variables observable so far when I'm needing to use a ternary conditional to adjust buttons or text depending on conditions needed. I'm not suing them everywhere just fyi lol.

Comment: That's fine, just mentioned that based on how you added `.obs` to `Permission.camera.status`. GetX is great and makes a lot of things easier. Just be sure to still try and understand whats going on under the hood with streams and general Flutter/Dart concepts. GetX can abstract a lot of things away and in some cases at the expense of one understanding Flutter better if they rely on GetX for everything.