# Flutter Future<bool>, RX<bool>, and regular bool confusion and how to get the value of one from the other

Tags: flutter, future, boolean-logic, flutter-getx

I'm new to flutter and just learned about GetX so I'm trying to incorporate it into my app as much as possible. In this example I'm trying to get permissions for storage and have a widget reactive if it is or isnt granted to change text and color and such.

My function for calling storage permissions gives back a future like so...

```
  Future<bool> requestStoragePermissions() async {
    final storagePermissionStatus = await Permission.storage.request();

    if (storagePermissionStatus == PermissionStatus.granted) {
      debugPrint('Notification Permission Granted');
      return true;
    } else if (storagePermissionStatus == PermissionStatus.denied) {
      debugPrint('Notification Permission Denied');
    } else if (storagePermissionStatus == PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied) {
      debugPrint('Notification Permission Permanently Denied');
      await openAppSettings();
    }

    if (storagePermissionStatus == PermissionStatus.granted) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

in my permissions screen I have a method to choose which permissions I want depending on the argument sent into the class...

```
Future<bool> checkPermissions() async {
  print('Permission Type: ' + permissionType.toString());
  bool statusGranted = false;
  if (permissionType == Permission.camera) {
    statusGranted = await _permissionController.requestCameraPermission();
  } else if (permissionType == Permission.location) {
    statusGranted = await _permissionController.requestLocationPermissions();
  } else if (permissionType == Permission.notification) {
    statusGranted = await _permissionController.requestNotificationPermissions();
  } else if (permissionType == Permission.storage) {
    statusGranted = await _permissionController.requestStoragePermissions();
  }
  return Future<bool>.value(statusGranted);
}
```

I change the return to future but I did have it as just statusGranted as I'm playing around with it. How do I use the value Future in a conditional statement? I keep getting error that I cant compare Future to a bool.

Here I am trying to conditionally set the button icon to be different depending on if permission is granted or not.

```
SizedBox(
  width: 100,
  child: _permissionGranted.value == false
      ? const Icon(
          Icons.no_photography,
          size: 40,
          color: Colors.red,
        )
      : const Icon(
          Icons.camera_alt,
          size: 40,
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
),
```

The _permissionsGranted.value I put in there cause I had checkPermission() == falsa there at first. Now I'm just trying random things and falling further from where I need to be which is why I've come here for help.

On a side note as the Title says. Now we have 3 different Bools to work with. Is there a proper way to use these interchangably?

EDIT:

The checkPermission is getting checked everytime this button gets pressed...

```
Obx(
    () => ElevatedButton(
      child: _permissionGranted.value == false ? const Text('Click Me') : const Text('Done'),
      onPressed: _permissionGranted.value == false
          ? () async {
              await checkPermissions();
            }
          : null,
```

I basically was creating this button inside my screen widget and decided to extract it into its own widget so I could use more of the same button to check different permission checks on the same page.

Comment: When you call the checkPermissions() and requestStoragePermissions()? you can share this code.

Comment: II have edited my OP, in the end I made a workaround and did regular bool checks inside my permissionsController methods which I send to my permissionScreen widget. i was trying to use the checkPermission that returns a future<bool> method as the conditional for a ternary expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're confused about `Futures` then I suggest reading up on [async programming in Dart](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await)   as its an important concept to understand. It's a `Future` because it has to `await` the process checking the permission before the value of the `bool` is set.

A `Future` of any type just means that the value won't be returned until some other process occurs ie...requesting data from some external API or checking permissions etc...

`RxBool` vs `bool` is a stream of a `boolean` vs a regular `boolean`. Using `Obx` requires a stream inside of it because its job is to listen to the stream and rebuild when the value of the stream updates. And as you know to access the actual primitive `bool` you use `.value`.

In your case, you have a bunch of logic in your screen and that could all live in the GetX class and clean up your UI code. All the UI should care about is the value of `controller.permissionGranted`

Your `Future<bool> checkPermissions()` doesn't need to return a `bool` it just needs to update the value of `permissionGranted`. All the other functions can be private because the UI doesn't need to know about what `checkPermissions()` does.

```
// all of this lives in the GetX class
  Future<void> checkPermissions() async {
    if (permissionType == Permission.camera) {
      permissionGranted.value = await _requestCameraPermission();
    } else if (permissionType == Permission.location) {
      permissionGranted.value = await _requestLocationPermissions();
    } // continue with others...
  }
```

And here's an example of how that could look in the UI

```
class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final controller = Get.find<PermissionController>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Obx(
          () => ElevatedButton(
              child: !controller.permissionGranted
                      .value // note the ! saves from having to write "== false"
                  ? const Text('Click Me')
                  : const Text('Done'),
              onPressed: !controller.permissionGranted.value
                  ? () async {
                      await controller.checkPermissions();
                    }
                  : null),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that definitely cleaned up my code a lot. I am understanding the Futures much better since first being shown them in my flutter course I was doing now that I'm actually playing around with them in practical usage.

Answer (score 0):

After a few more hours beating my head against the wall trying to figure this out I came across a forum that educated me in the fact the I could use async in an onPressed: property. So I created an RX in my permissionsController to change for each permission check I did and used that as the ternary condition to change the widgets behavior. So I had to add this method which takes in the bool as the method finishes successfully

```
void permissionGranted() {
  if (permissionType == Permission.camera) {
    _permissionGranted.value = _permissionController.mediaGranted.value;
  } else if (permissionType == Permission.location) {
    _permissionGranted.value = _permissionController.locationGranted.value;
  } else if (permissionType == Permission.notification) {
    _permissionGranted.value = _permissionController.notificationsGranted.value;
  } else if (permissionType == Permission.storage) {
    _permissionGranted.value = _permissionController.storageGranted.value;
  }
}
```

And as I showed in my post edit I now used the checkPermission method inside the ternary statement rather than trying to use is AS the ternary statement.

```
Obx(
  () => ElevatedButton(
    child: _permissionGranted.value == false ? const Text('Click Me') : const Text('Done'),
    onPressed: _permissionGranted.value == false
        ? () async {
            await checkPermissions();
          }
        : null,
```

and here is my updated checkPermission method...

```
bool statusGranted = false;
Future<bool> checkPermissions() async {
  //print('Permission Type: ' + permissionType.toString());
  if (permissionType == Permission.camera) {
    statusGranted = await _permissionController.requestCameraPermission();
    permissionGranted();
  } else if (permissionType == Permission.location) {
    statusGranted = await _permissionController.requestLocationPermissions();
    permissionGranted();
  } else if (permissionType == Permission.notification) {
    statusGranted = await _permissionController.requestNotificationPermissions();
    permissionGranted();
  } else if (permissionType == Permission.storage) {
    statusGranted = await _permissionController.requestStoragePermissions();
    permissionGranted();
  }
  return statusGranted;
}
```

Still very much confused about the interchangeability of having 3 different Boolean types to mix and use though. the Future, the RX and the regular bool.